# REACT: How can I access another functiın return?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to access myCitiesArray that is in HandleCitiesArray func. I need to access redux using useSelector hook. How can I do that? I want to delete an object inside of initialState.myCities array

```
import ActionTypes from "../constants/ActionTypes";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const initialState = {
  myCities: [],
  aCity: {},
  getCityById: {},
  filteredCities: [],
};

const HandleCitiesArray = () => {
  const myCitiesArray = useSelector((state) => state.allWeathers.myCities);
  return myCitiesArray;
};

export const WeatherReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  console.log(HandleCitiesArray().myCitiesArray); //try to print it here
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.GETBY_CITYNAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        aCity: payload,
        myCities: [...state.myCities, payload],
      };
    case ActionTypes.GETCITYBYID:
      return {
        ...state,
        getCityById: payload,
        myCities: HandleCitiesArray().filter(
          (item) => parseInt(item.id) !== parseInt(payload.id)
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

You already have access to the state in the reducer function where you can grab `myCities` same as you did on this line  `myCities: [...state.myCities, payload],` and log it out

Comment: but I am trying to delete an item from myCities array. How could I do that

Comment: state.myCities.filter(
          (item) => parseInt(item.id) !== parseInt(payload.id)

Comment: I fix like this  myCities: [
          ...initialState.myCities,
          ...state.myCities.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id),
        ],